# Align a mesh with VTK Camera (Visual representation of camera, mesh that moves and rotate with it)

Tags: c++, camera, rotation, orientation, vtk

I am having troubles with the different parameters of the vtkCamera. I have a vtkRenderWindow and a vtkCamera associated.

What I want to do is creating a visual representation of the camera. That is assigning a mesh (e.g a cone), that moves and rotates with the camera so the camera is visible on the scene (I have a camera feed and another global scene where I want to see that other camera move around).

However, I am having troubles aligning a mesh with the camera. I set the position and the focal point of the camera, but I don't quite understand how to align the mesh. It revolves around knowing the front vector of the camera, where it is looking at, but I cannot seem to know where to get it as the orientation or the focal point do not help.

How do I proceed to align a mesh with the camera? Which parameters do I have to be looking at? Thank you.

Sincerely,
Albert.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you right, but you might want to have a look at vtkCameraActor -- a visual representation of camera frustum
http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCameraActor.html

And this example that shows you how to use it
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/CameraActor

Hope this helps,

Miro